# Getting sum from a left table of leftjoined table

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are the tables and the SQL query. I am doing a left join and trying to get SUM of a column that's in the left table and count from the right table.

Is it possible to get both in 1 query?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QuxG1DLgWJ8aGXNbnnwU1/1

```
select
  s.test,
  count(distinct s.name),
  sum(s.score) score, -- need accurate score
  count(a.id) attempts -- need accurate attempt count
from question s 
left join attempts a on s.id = a.score_id
group by s.test
```

```
create table question (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  test varchar(25),
  name varchar(25),
  score int
);


create table attempts (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  score_id int,
  attempt_no int
);


insert into question (test, name, score) values
('test1','name1', 10),
('test1','name2', 15),
('test1','name3', 20),
('test1','name4', 25),

('test2','name1', 15),
('test2','name2', 25),
('test2','name3', 30),
('test2','name4', 20);


insert into attempts (score_id, attempt_no) values
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pre-aggregate before the `join`:

```
select q.test, count(distinct q.name),
       sum(q.score) score, -- need accurate score
       sum(a.num_attempts) attempts -- need accurate attempt count
from question q left join
     (select a.score_id, count(*) as num_attempts
      from attempts a
      group by a.score_id
     ) a
     on q.id = a.score_id
group by q.test;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QuxG1DLgWJ8aGXNbnnwU1/1) is a db-fiddle.

Comment: The pre-aggregate works great. I know the database schema design is not done the right way but there's a reason for that. My biggest issue is that the attempts table has around 6B+ records so pre-aggregation is kind of very slow. Can I use any other efficient solution where it only aggregates the relevant data?

Comment: @trio . . . Any summarization of 6 billion rows is going to take time.  I don't think there is a way to avoid that, unless you are filtering the results.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon said above, you can pre-aggregate, but his answer will get you the incorrect number of attempts, unfortunately. This is due to an issue with how you're structuring your DB schema. It looks like your `question` table really records scores of attempts at questions, and your `attempts` table is unnecessary. You should really have a `question` table that simply contains an ID and a name for the question, and a `attempts` table that contains an attempt ID, question ID, name, and score.

```
create table question (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  test varchar(25)
);


create table attempts (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  question_id int,
  name varchar(25),
  score int
);
```

Then your query becomes as simple as:

```
select 
  q.id as question_id, 
  count(distinct a.name) as attempters, 
  sum(a.score) as total_score,
  count(a.id) as total_attempts
from question q join attempts a on q.id = a.question_id
group by q.id
```